# Costs of Renting

Tags: rental, equipment

Hi guys, I was wondering what the average cost of renting at 744 recorder, 442 mixer, a couple of wireless lavs and wireless transmitters. I'll be making some phone calls to ask around and I wanted to see if I can, perhaps, assess some sort of standard pricing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorder, probably $75 - $150 per day.  Mixer, $25 - $55 per day.  Wireless mics, $55 - $125 per day, depending on the quality of the packs and the type of mic you get.  It also depends on how long you're renting.  Most rental houses will do 3 day weeks or give cheaper weekend rentals since it is not a peak rental time.  It can really vary a lot depending on location, time, etc.  Always shop around though.

I would recommend looking for a sound person that already has these items.  It will probably end up being cheaper to pay him or her a day rate including equipment than to rent the equipment you listed.

Location Sound is good, as birdhousesound said.  I also like the guys at [Coffey Sound](http://www.coffeysound.com/Contact-Us.html).  If you're on the east coast or southeast, I can also recommend some rental locations.

Good luck!

Comment: @VCProd what are your east / southeast recommendations?

Comment: @Steve PC&E in Atlanta has some rental equipment.  Prices are pretty good, but you're not going to find nice high end audio gear there.  Best bet is calling one of the gajillion sound guys in town like Aaron Segal.  In Boston, I've had really good success with Talmas.  In NYC, I highly recommend Gotham Sound.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your location, but if you're in LA try [Location Sound](http://www.locationsound.com/proaudio/ls/index.html).